# Modeling JSON result in Core Data Editor

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data

I'm learning Core Data and I need to create an Entity called `Country`. I'm getting this response from my API and I'm not sure how to create and store the JSON response in my country entity.

```
{
    "total_count":10,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Spain",
            "population" : 45.000,
            "location" : {
                "latitude" : 29.567423,
                "longitude" : -5.675326
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "France",
            "population" : 25.000,
            "location" : {
                "latitude" : 29.567423,
                "longitude" : -5.675326
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Germany",
            "population" : 15.000,
            "location" : {
                "latitude" : 29.567423,
                "longitude" : -5.675326
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The parent fields (`name`, `population`) are not problem, but how can I set the child fields (`location` key) in the entity graph? With an `NSDictionary` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possibilities.

You can create two separate attributes like (`latitude`, `longitude`) having type (`double`, `double`) and at fetch time create location with both values or you can create `CGPoint` with both of values and then create string from `CGPoint` and store them

```
CGPoint location = CGPointMake(latitude, longitude);
NSString *stringLocation = NSStringFromCGPoint(point);
```

store that string and fetch it and then again convert into `CGpoint` and use it

```
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointFromString(stringLocation);
```

Comment: Create a relationship from location property into Country entity to a new entity called countryLocation with two floats as properties would be a good choice?

Comment: I don't think in that case need to add another entity. You can simply create two columns one for latitude and another for longitude.

Comment: I would not talk about columns but simply attributes. Core Data is not a database.